# drupal 7, how to select multiple servers in LDAP Authorization?

Tags: commerce

I was using multiple servers i.e one is ADS and the other one is Open LDAP in drupal 7 for the authentication. LDAP Authorization Configuration is showing both the servers with a radio button option, where i can choose only one option. But i need to pick both the option. Please could anybody help me out.

If there is any option. Just am new to Drupal. If there is a option, please share with me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge -- unless your LDAP schemas are very similar or you want to write some custom LDAP queries you cannot query 2 ldap sources "at once". Actually in Perl I think you can have 2 sources for a query, but in PHP you can only have server connection ...

So, typically you just waterfall a request through X ldap servers hoping 1 will succeed. I haven't used the drupal 7 LDAP module yet because it was buggy when I was looking at it months ago.

You can do LDAP stuff in drupal with php by hand using [user_external_login_register()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7) which I've done in drupal 7 for various LDAP authentication points.

A small [random example off of the web](http://yetanotherprogrammingblog.com/content/drupal-7-external-authentication-sample-code).

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your posting. Enterly i don't need to use the custom modules for the LDAP authentication. The users were in ADS, and logging to the drupal site, the  authentication is very good based upon the role.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your posting. Enterly i don't need to use the custom modules for the LDAP authentication. The users were in ADS, and logging to the drupal site, the  authentication is very good based upon the role. Now, just i need to add one more authentication from "openldap" server. Drupal can able to authenticate the users from both ADS and from openldap. For ADS users, i created a role and for openldap users, i can't able to create a role. Can you please help me out by giving a sample modules with the examples.